# Copy files with multiple search criteria

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to copy files in a directory into a new folder. The script works on one file type, but I have 6 types I need to search for. I thought I could use a bar ("|") like you can with a Regex but that didn't work. Then I tried using an array and had no luck there.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMove.Click
        Dim sourceDir As String
        sourceDir = txtMovePath.Text
        Dim foundFile As Object = Nothing

        Dim graphicsFldr As String
        graphicsFldr = sourceDir + "\Graphics\"

        For Each foundFile In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(sourceDir, _
          Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, _
          "*.cgm|*.eps|*.svg|*.wmf|*.jpg|*.png|*.iso")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, graphicsFldr & My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(foundFile))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Module mainModule
    Sub Main()
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub
```

Comment: That is VB.Net not VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 Dim arr = {"*cgm","*.eps","*.svg","*.wmf","*.jpg","*.png","*.iso"}
 For Each foundFile In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(sourceDir, _
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, arr)
     My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, graphicsFldr & My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(foundFile))
 Next
```